# script Table as Create via SSMS doesn't show unique index

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Using SQL Server Management Studio 2008, why can't I see unique index ( not primary key ) when I generate Create Table SQL code?

It includes only primary key constraint. Is it by design ? There is a possibility to get SQL code for index creation via right mouse click on an index and  "Script index as", but it is another step.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Is the "Script Unique Keys" option set to TRUE in your SSMS?

In SSMS, Tools -> Options will get you to the pop-up window shown below.
[image]

Answer (score 15):

Note that in SSMS 2012, you have to set "Script indexes" to TRUE to script out unique indexes.

[image: SSMS 2012 Screenshot]